# use netty developing a game ,please help me?

Tags: netty

I am a student, the latest in the study netty, feel it great. I want to use it to write a timely interactive little game. Don't know how to write disposal layer. Separate processing business logic module, Handler in how to deal with it? Do not know how to start. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best start would be to have a look at the examples [1] that are provided by netty. Once you are done with that come back with more specific questions.

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example

Answer (score 0):

The user guide http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/ is also a good place to start.

Remember to click on the javadoc links because the javadoc contains alot of information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Netty Game Server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) I have written and published to Github. This has both client and the server side of a multi player game. It maybe a bit more involved than your requirements but the [wiki](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/wiki/Jetserver-internal-details-and-how-it-works.) page might help you out to understand netty usage.